# ImageViews and constraints in ios

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, interface-builder

I am trying to make a simple tic tac toe game. I have made the game scene in interface builder and I have an ImageView for the game grid with 9 ImageViews which can be either x or o on top of the grid.

The game is working fine but now I am trying to add constraints so that it displays properly on all devices. I managed to add the proper constraints to the grid so that it shows properly but I can't make the 9 image views to stay properly on the bigger ImageView (the grid).

Is there anyway that if I adjust the big ImageView (of the grid) it could auto-adjust the small ImageViews? Could it work if I add them as subviews for the big one? I noticed two options: clip subviews and autoresize subviews.

What would be the easiest way to get them to display properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do so is to use a CollectionView.

Applying constraints to 9 imagesviews will harder but if you want to apply contraints 
you can watch this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G53PuA_TlXk

Comment: Is there a way to make them display properly on all devices without constraints?

Comment: you can make various copies of your storyboard with different screen sizes & on app load you can determine device type ( iPhone - iPad ) and load it's storyboard

Comment: Cool. Thanks! Does this have a big impact on app size or efficiency?

Comment: No, but Apple see that doing constraints is easier as if you like to change any thing in your storyboard you will do it once & will affect all devices.
but now any change must be done to all storyboards.
before size classes most of universal apps were done this way.
Please don't forget to mark answer as correct

Comment: If I have a UIView with a UIImageView as its subview in Interface Builder can I make the UIImageView resize automatically when I resize the parent view? Also can I make it so that it stays centered in the parent view?